# Setting up Google Routes API

Tags: google-routes-api

I am struggling to set-up a HTTP request for the Google routes API and was wondering if anyone could provide me with an example HTTP request that I could try.

Tried various HTTP requests expecting the JSON response but got nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are quite a few example requests in the documentation, all you need is an API key from a project correctly setup (also explained in the documentation), e.g. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/compute_route_directions#example_http_route_request